# Do I need to keep updating my wallet address in faucets?

Tags: wallet, faucets

I notice that my wallet address keeps changing and I am wondering two things:

1. Why does the address dynamically change?
2. Do I need to update the wallet address in the faucets I use in order to receive the satoshis?

It will be a pain if I have to constantly update my wallet address in the faucets.

Answer (score 2):

You're using a HD Wallet which specifically avoids reused addresses. You can of course reuse an address, so putting the same address into faucets is probably the only way to spend the low value input.

So, yes, reuse the address

Comment: @Wizard Actually, re-using the same address does not help with spending low value inputs. They're still separate inputs. In practice OP would still of course keep using the same address for convenience reasons.

Comment: @BrianSimms If possible, try to make the payments as large as you trust the faucet. Miniscule paymets will cost you more in fees than they're worth (also when you spend the money!). But if you can save up for a few weeks (or months) before doing one payout, it might be worth it.

Comment: @Jannes whoops, you're absolutely right